# Boiling sodium hydroxide in stainless steel cup: Solution turning to a blue color

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, metal, alloy

I boiled highly concentrated sodium hydroxide in a stainless steel cup. This created a blackish layer on the bottom of the cup and turned the colour of the sodium hydroxide solution to blueish.

Am I right to assume that there was some oxidation happening at the surface of steel? Are any oxides of metals, present in common stainless steel, known to have a blue colour when dissolved in an aqueous solution?

Comment: Is your steel cup stainless steel?

Comment: Stainless steel resists to oxidation by air and water. It may be attacked by acids and bases.

Comment: Maybe try a titanium cup from a shop that sells camping or outdoors supplies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you say stainless steel? Stainless steel is an alloy of $\ce{Ni, Cr, Fe}$ with other trace elements, and owes its apparent resistance to corrosion to a protective, adherent, coating of mixed chrome, nickel, and iron oxides. A large amount is probably $\ce{Cr^3+}$, which is amphoteric and will dissolve in hydroxide solution. Once the protective coating is breached chromium will react in base similarly to aluminum. The potential to $\ce{[Cr(OH)4]^-}$ is about $\pu{+1.2 V}$. Stainless steel can be much more reactive than pure iron if the protective layer is continually disrupted.

Comment: Would that solution be blue?  I thought tetrahydroxochromate (III) was green.

Comment: @Oscar Lanzi: This probably due to $\ce{Ni}$ complex.

Comment: Very interesting indeed, thank you. Now I will need to find a more etching resistant alternative to the steel... Hm

Comment: The "color" is subjective.  To discover which metal was attacked requires  actual analysis.  The reason I suggested Cr was that I have had some experience with SS corrosion and chrome was somewhat implicated and chrome is much more amphoteric than either iron or nickel.